# andorid Gcm Login with some account and uninstall and again login with other account immediately causing multiple message receive for account(reg-id)

Tags: android, message, google-cloud-messaging

First in app i am login in with some account information and then after i am registering device id with my server... it works perfectly
But now some one uninstalling app and  so i can't remove device id....

I have given functionality if user logout then i can unregister by my app and delete id from my serer...

Now scenario is if user login in app and then after uninstall the app so device id not removed from my server and immediatly user isntall app and login with differnt account device id will be generated will be differnt so i can't identify and now new entry will be inserted in my server 
and this phone will receive messages for both of accounts (device ids)...

Hopefully you got my question...i want how i detect or identify so only one account's messages received or send from server..... any have suggestion for this?

If want me to explain more then let me know...

advance thx for helping

Answer (score 0):

First of all, once you uninstall the app from your phone, the GCM key associated with that particular app will be destroyed with the app itself (unless you've stored it in a file or something). So there is no way the phone could receive any notifications sent to the GCM id which has already been removed from your phone.

Secondly, the key will remain in your server if the user uninstalls the app. This is normal behaviour. You could just update the key the next time the user logs in with the new app, replacing the old one, so that newer notifications are sent to the new id and not the old id.

Comment: you got it right but thing is...lets go step by step
1) user 1 login device id ==1 and uninstall....server have user 1 and device id 1
2) now from the same device user again install app and now login with other account  so user 2 device id 2
3) now i am sending message as server have both device id this mobile device will receive 2 times message....got the problem ?
this is case when user 1 once uninstall app and he / she not have logged in again.....if user 1 logged in again then it will works as you have explained...

Comment: I don't get the "install again" part. As far as I know you can install an app only once. And for managing different accounts, you don't need different GCM ids for each account. GCM id is just for identifying the device/app; not the user account. If two accounts are sharing the same device/app they will have the same GCM id.

Comment: k again install again part...
1) user 1 installs and uninstall app
2) now user 1 install again app after uninstalling and now he / she login with different account (my side)
3) thing is that i should get same device id (GCM ID) always if this is same app and mobile but i am getting different device id....
now is it k or explain more ?

Comment: When you uninstall an app and install it again, a new gcm id is generated. The old id will totally be useless. You cannot receive notifications sent to the old id.

Comment: sorry but i am receiving it thats problem....again let me check one more time so we can be sure about this problem

Comment: Follow these steps and you'll be fine: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: hi thx for info...and link...i have already follow this page and implemented the same code and i have tested it as told and problem is still coming...can you pls check this problem at your side is it coming or not ?